# Advice with Genetic Algorithm learning to walk game

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I have a project in AI coming up, and we can make anything we want. I have this idea, you DRAW a monster. Lines are its bones and muscles, dots are its joints, you decide how those joints can bend etc etc. Then you make a Neural Network/Genetic algorithm and it learns to walk and avoid obstacles.

My professor said that my idea is good and approved it. The only problem is, I don't know how to start and with what tool. I am thinking Unity or Unreal Engine, but I don't know if that is a good idea.

Do you have any advice on which programming language or gaming engine I should use? I don't want to mess with things that aren't AI oriented for too long.

Comment: 'Drawing monster' as you say it alone will take idk may be years. Better start with a given monster and teach it to learn to walk. Engine doesn't matter, but Unity relatively has a much bigger community, so it could come in handy.

Comment: Unless you have specific reasons to go 3D, I would forget about Game Engine and start in 2D, with something "simpler", e.g. discard gravity/equilibrium, focus on geometrical shape. You might want to define 3 classes of movements, i.e. move forward, crawl forward and jump forward, and evolve them genetically first, before genetically evolving the right sequence of movements to reach the furthest point of the map, from left to right. Neural Networks don't seem to be necessary, though one might find a use of them.

Comment: This is a total *flashback* for me!  I did something very similar for my thesis project in 1996.  My I suggest you start **very** simple with a 2D hopper (1 foot, 2 body pieces, 2 joints) as the shape.  For the motion, start with the concept of a *wind-up-toy* kind of thing, where you are just evolving a *gait*.  I found that a minimum of 3 steps where needed for a 2 jointed figure.  That was a matrix of target 2 joint positions x 3 time periods = 6 parameters.  That means in time period 1, the 2 joints are activated to get to their target angle, at period 2 to their target angle and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to code everything yourself? [This](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic) library offers neuroevolution (genetic algorithm on nerual networks) in Javascript. You can combine this with a drawing library like [P5.js](https://p5js.org/)

See some examples of neuroevolution with [Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic):

- [Agar.IO AI](https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/articles/agario/)
- [Target-seeking AI](https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/articles/targetseeking/)

Comment: If you are going to use javascript, here is my genetic algorithm javascript npm package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/geneticalgorithm - which has several examples *(like traveling salesmen)*, documentation, and test cases.